# How can i use QGroupBox with two views?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

i have two views (first and second) vertical aligment

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QSplitter,QGroupBox, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from .First import First
from .Second import Second

class LateralMenu(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.plotview = QGroupBox("Group of views")
        self.text = "Menu Lateral"
        self.layout = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        self.layout_plotview = QVBoxLayout()
        self.First = First()
        self.Second = Second()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.First)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Second)

        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.layout)
        self.plotview.setLayout(self.layout_plotview)
        self.setLayout(self.plotview)
```

i want to put those views in a QGroupBox, but i am getting this error:     self.setLayout(self.plotview)
TypeError: setLayout(self, QLayout): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGroupBox'

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error reports: you're trying to set a *layout* (which has to be a subclass of [QLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html), such as QGridLayout, etc), but the provided argument is a QGroupBox, which is a subclass of QWidget.

If you want to add the QGroupBox to the current widget, you should set a layout for that widget and *then* add the groupbox to that layout:

```
    def initUI(self):
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        # ...
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.plotview)
```

If the groupbox is going to be the *only* "main" widget, there's no need for that, though: you can just subclass from QGroupBox (instead of QWidget):

```
class LateralMenu(QGroupBox):
    # ...
    def initUi(self):
        self.setTitle("Group of views")
        self.text = "Menu Lateral"

        self.layout_plotview = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout_plotview)

        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        self.First = First()
        self.Second = Second()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.First)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.Second)
        self.layout_plotview.addWidget(self.splitter)
```

Note that I've changed some names (most importantly, `self.layout` has become `self.splitter`), and that's for clarity: while QSplitter behaves similarly to a layout, it is *not* a layout, but a QWidget; naming it "layout" might create a lot of confusion.
Also, you should not overwrite existing class properties (such as, indeed, `self.layout`).
Finally, avoid using capitalized names for variables and attributes: both `First` and `Second` instances should be lower case (read more about this in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: right now i cannot see the two views (First and Second)

Comment: @jdode I skipped the `__init__` because it was unnecessary for the example, it **obviously** has to be there, otherwise `initUi` would never be called.